# Leetcode, works in test case but not when submitted

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, immutability

Hi this is my first question in StackOverflow, so it may not be perfect.

I'm trying to solve this question from leetcode using python3.10
https://leetcode.com/problems/encode-and-decode-tinyurl/

My code works in the test case, but gives error when submitted. But then, when I add that case to the test case, it works agian.

As leetcode suggested, I added `__init__` function in the class, and tried my best to make the variables in the encode and decode functions immutable (for ex, creating empty list every time and converting the lists to string objects so that the function returns string objects, not lists)

I tried my best but I can't find a solution. Thanks for the help.

```
import math, random

class Codec:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = 3
        self.n = 0 

    def isprime(self, n):
        if n < 2:
            return False
        for i in range(2, n//2 + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True

    def randprime(self, min, max):
        a = random.randint(min, max)
        while self.isprime(a) != True:
            a = random.randint(min, max)
        return a

    def Gete(self, phi_n):
        e = 3
        for i in range(phi_n-1):
            if math.gcd(e, phi_n) == 1:
                return e
            else:
                e += 1

    def Getd(self, e, phi_n):
        d = 3
        while True:
            if (1 - d*e) % phi_n == 0:
                return d
            else:
                d += 1

    def encode(self, shortUrl: str) -> str:
        p = self.randprime(2, 100)
        q = self.randprime(2, 100)
        while p == q:
            p = self.randprime(1000,5000)

        self.n = p*q
        phi_n = (p-1)*(q-1)

        e = self.Gete(phi_n)
        self.d = self.Getd(e, phi_n)

        as_url = []
        encryp_url = []
        as_url = [ord(ch) for ch in shortUrl]
        encryp_url = [pow(ch, e, self.n) for ch in as_url]
        str_encrp_url = "".join(chr(ch) for ch in encryp_url)

        return str_encrp_url
    
    def decode(self, longUrl: str) -> str:
        decryp_url = []
        asc_longUrl = [ord(ch) for ch in longUrl]
        decryp_url = [pow(ch, self.d, self.n) for ch in asc_longUrl]
        message = "".join(chr(ch) for ch in decryp_url)
        return message
```

---------------added information (error and testcases)----------------
So when Submitt the code, I get an error like this.[The error raised when submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njif4.png)

So I add that to the testcase section and run the code, it works.[same case works in test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb6pH.png)

Also, it says in the question that the code will run with commands like this

```
"Your Codec object will be instantiated and called as such:
 codec = Codec()
 codec.decode(codec.encode(url))"
```

Comment: An error. What error? A testcase. Which testcase?

Comment: It seems like changing `self.d` and `self.n` each time you encode will prevent proper decoding.

Comment: If you call `encode()` twice, when you try to decode the first result it won't work because `self.d` and `self.n` are different.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Barmar, ok I think I get the problem. And I also just realized that I make d the public key and e as the private key, when it's opposite. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys thanks for the help. I don't know what I did, but it works now. The last thing I did was to change the range of the randdom primes (p and q) from (2~100) to (100~1000). And then it worked.

I don't know why though, I think its the math of the RSA algorithm I was trying to use.But it works now. Thank you gyus for your help again.

'''

```
def encode(self, shortUrl: str) -> str:
    p = self.randprime(100, 1000)
    q = self.randprime(100, 1000)
    while p == q:
        p = self.randprime(100,1000)

    n = p*q
    phi_n = (p-1)*(q-1)
    self.phi_n = phi_n

    self.e = self.Gete(phi_n)

    as_url = []
    encryp_url = []
    as_url = [ord(ch) for ch in shortUrl]
    encryp_url = [pow(ch, self.e, n) for ch in as_url]
    str_encrp_url = "".join(chr(ch) for ch in encryp_url)

    self.n = n

    return str_encrp_url
```

'''